# setting styles in <input> tag

Tags: html, css

why can't one set a style like the font size in an input tag, e.g.

```
<input style="font-size:20px" type="radio" name="a" value="a">some text</input>
```

Shouldn't the font attributes apply?

Secondly, what is the best way to do this then?

Thanks

Comment: For `type="text` input fields, you can set the color of the value text with a style attribute. This would seem to be for radio buttons and checkboxes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that it's because the CSS you're setting applies to the 'inner' tag of that input.

The thing you want styled is its Value, so you need to wrap your input inside a placeholder and style that.

For example:

```
<span style="font-size:40px">
    <input  type="radio" name="a" value="a">some text
    <input  type="radio" name="a" value="b">some text
</span>
```

Works as expected.

Comment: Also, input's are funny tags, they're meant to self close, putting </input> is technically illegal; even in XHTML input's are meant to read (simply) <input type='x' val='y' />

Comment: I see, thanks Russ.  So the style doesn't do much ... anything ... for this input tag with type radio?

Answer (score 3):

The best way to go about this is providing the style deceleration within an external stylesheet, or perhaps at the top of the document.  Inline styles are typically what you want to avoid if at all possible, as it becomes confusing for later changes and can cause really dirty specificity issues.

An example of a fix:

HTMl (example)

```
<div id="form">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="a" />
</div>
```

CSS (example)

```
#form input {
   font-size: 20px;   
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I was just shifting to this.

Answer (score 2):

There's not a lot you can do to style a radio button, however:

```
<input type="radio" name="radiogroup" id="radio-1">
<label for="radio-1">Radio button 1</label>
```

you can style the label...

Comment: What do labels really by you, with the "for" attribute?  Seems like lots of extra text/typing, rather than using a div like GoGoGarrett pointed out.

Comment: @Ray K When the text of a label is clicked, if it's `for` attribute is set, the input whose id matches the `for` value gets selected. Makes checkboxes/radiobuttons much easier to select. Also, labels are used by accessibility agents like screen-readers.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
<input type="radio" name="a" value="a"><span style="font-size: 50px;">some text</span></input>
```

If you wrap the text with a span\p tag you will be able to style the inner text of that tag.

Comment: `<input />` is most certainly **not** a container element.

Comment: I didn't -1 (and shame on whoever did without commenting), however this adds more superfluous markup, as well as the fact `input` [tags shouldn't have content inside them](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.4) (like `img` tags).

Comment: Thanks.  I guess Tieson's comment clarifies that input is not a container element.  Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question already has an accepted answer, but I figure it's worth mentioning this:

It may be better to either associate a `<label>` tag with each radio input (using the `for` attribute of the label) or wrapping each radio input with a label tag. This lets your user click on the **text** to select the radio input instead of having to aim for a rather small circle.

So your markup looks like so:

```
<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radios" value="something 1" /> 
<label for="radio1">Something 1</label>

<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radios" value="something 2" /> 
<label for="radio2">Something 2</label>

<input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radios" value="something 3" /> 
<label for="radio3">Something 3</label>
```

Radio inputs are grouped into mutually exclusive selections by their name, which the group will share. The value specified in the `for` attribute of the label will match the `id` attribute of the radio input you want selected. So in the sample above, if you click on the text "Something 1", the radio input that is id'd as `radio1` gets selected.

You can then style the text of the label to your heart's content.

This is in regards to the second part of your question,

> "Secondly, what is the best way to do this then?"

Answer (score -2):

```css
#input {
  background-color: black;
  color: green;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<input id="input" value="Value" />
```